Shell script type installer is completely blank and font is blurry
I am trying to install the following shell script file from Xilinx Vivado, but whenever I execute the file, the installer is missing fonts and is dark. Moreover, you can see that the fonts are weird at the top of the installation bar. I also noticed this same issue with my VSCode, as in the top of the bar the font is also glitchy.
I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 on Oracle VirtualBox. This setup doesn't have any external GPU and I have attached the Virtual Machine's Configuration in the image.

I am attaching the images here:
Glitchy installer:

Glitchy font on VSCode top bar:

Note;

Your question is about video issues but I do not see any mention of the GPU or video driver in use. Please use edit and add this info to the question. Please not as a comment.

It seems the issue was with the shell. Previously I installed Z shell but decided again to change back to bash script. But unfortunately, I uninstalled Zshell first which might have changed my terminal to bash Shell, but the shell directory still pointed to Zshell's location which didn't exist in the system. So I had to change back the directory to bash script.
